# how to get next set of data using Hibernate

Tags: ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have 50000 records in MySQL am using spring + hibernate, and am using data tables to display the data,
4000 is maxResults,i have to update the table with next 4000 thousand records for that particular date.

Comment: Are you looking for [pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hibernate+pagination)?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination) link includes multiple ways to use hibernate's pagination feature - through HQL query, ScrollableResults API and with Hibernate Criteria

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, actually, setFirstResult will bring default database entry, not the entry from which i want.

Comment: You tried other methods included in the link above?